# ffmpeg. I want to connect pictures in a video. Does not work

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I use

ffmpeg -f -i  -r 24 -vcodec mjpeg -y test.mov

It's in python code

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -f image2 -i '
cmd += ' '.join([f'{i}' for i in jpg_list])
cmd += ' -r 24 -vcodec mjpeg'
cmd += f' -y {first_secv}.mkv'
```

I need codec mjpeg, 24 frames.

Comment: What is the error? Doea the  jpeg files are numbers without extension?

Comment: @ozs, I have glass_crack_v001_000001, glass_crack_v001_000002, glass_crack_v001_000003 etc.
I don't understand about extension. 
Error: Requested output format 'count' is not a suitable output format
.mov: Invalid argument

Comment: instead of ' '.join([f'{i}' for i in jpg_list]) try: -i glass_crack_v001_%6d . also check if converting to mp4 works

Comment: @ozs, yes, it's works! Thank you!
But I don't know name files. It's changed files.
This is working code.

  cmd = 'ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i'
  cmd += f' glass_crack_v001_%6d.jpg'
  cmd += ' -c:v mjpeg'
  cmd += f' -y test_video.mov'

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the iteration of a list then you need to add -i before each file name. but in case of many items it might be limited.

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -f image2 '
cmd += ' '.join([f'-i {i}' for i in jpg_list])
cmd += ' -r 24 -vcodec mjpeg'
cmd += f' -y {first_secv}.mkv'
```

in case all files has same name with numeric postfix then you can use %d format.

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i '
cmd += 'glass_crack_v001_%6d.jpg -c:v mjpeg'
cmd += f' -y {first_secv}.mkv''
```

Another option its to create a text file with the order of the images:

the file (lets call it input.txt for the example) format should be as (2 lines for example):

```
file sea_v001_14479.jpg
file glass_crack_v001_000002
file /home/user/Dev/TEST/to\ sort/exp_1_00001.jpg # incase of space (add \ before the space) and -safe 0 in the ffmpeg command
```

and then the command would be :

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -framerate 24 -safe 0 -i input.txt -c:v mjpeg'
cmd += f' -y {first_secv}.mkv'
```

Comment: I decide. But a new problem. A have files like as sea_v001_14479.jpg, sea_v001_14479.jpg etc. And sea_v001_%5d.jpg' doesn't work. Because sea_v001_14479.jpg it's start file.

Comment: @Alexander, I added to the answer another option for this case

Comment: I try. And another  problem. I have folder 'to sort'. And a have error /home/alexander/Dev/TEST/to: No such file or directory.
It doesn't read 'to sort', it reads 'to'. I use r-line, and '//'. It's doesn't work.

Comment: Add quates to the path: "home/alexander/Dev/TEST/to sort/"

Comment: error: /home/alexander/Dev/TEST/to sort/input.txt: Invalid data found when processing input.
I write in input.txt:

file "/home/alexander/Dev/TEST/to sort/exp_1_00001.jpg"

Comment: @Alexander, remove the quotes, add \ after the "to" and in the ffmpeg cmd add -safe 0 before the -i